# Implementing generic interface in generic class

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm new to generic types, and was wondering how could I correctly implement the generic interface in a generic class, so the determination of type would be delayed to moment when I'm instantiating an object of this generic class.

My code looks as follows:

```
package org.processor.interfaces;

import org.filter.interfaces.IFile;

public interface ProcessorResult<T> {

 public IFile getFile();
 public String getProcessorName();
 public Class<? extends Processor<T>> getProcessorClass();
 public T getResult();  
}
```

And class which implements that interface:

```
package org.processor.interfaces.impl;
import org.filter.interfaces.IFile;
import org.processor.interfaces.Processor;
import org.processor.interfaces.ProcessorResult;

public class ProcessorResultImpl<T> implements ProcessorResult<T> {

private T result;
private String processorName;
private IFile file;

public  ProcessorResultImpl(T result) {
  this.t = result;
}

@Override
public IFile getFile() {
  return file;
}

@Override
public String getProcessorName() {
  return processorName;
}

@Override
public Class<? extends Processor<T>> getProcessorClass() {
  return null;
}

@Override
public T getResult() {
  return t;
}
}
```

The moment when I want to instantiate the object of this class is in method which returns ProcessorResult as follows(this is only for sake of demonstration):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.filter.interfaces.IFile;
import org.processor.interfaces.Processor;
import org.processor.interfaces.ProcessorFilter;
import org.processor.interfaces.ProcessorResult;

public class ProcessorLineCountImpl<T> implements Processor<T> {

  private ProcessorFilter<T> processorFilter;
  private String name;

  public ProcessorLineCountImpl() {

  }

  public ProcessorResult<T> process(IFile file) {
    int count = 0;
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file.openInputStream())) {
      while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String word = sc.next();
        if (word.indexOf("\\") == -1) {
          count++;
        }
      }
   return null;
}
return null;

@Override
public String getName() {
  return name;
}

@Override
public void setFilter(ProcessorFilter<T> filter) {
   this.processorFilter = filter;
}
```

In that case I'm getting **syntax error**:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ProcessorResultImpl<Long> to 
ProcessorResult<T>
```

**Questions:**

1. How it could be properly done as I'm out of ideas and couldn't find any solution on the web.
2. Is it a good approach to delay the determination of type till instantiation of object ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This doesn't make total sense - if it's *generic*, then why do you want to hard-code a `Long`?

Comment: Where is this `process` method defined?

Comment: `process` needs to return `ProcessorResult<Long>`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I know, because I'm total newbie to generics, and I would really love to know how it coulde be done correctly, as you mentioned I would like it to not be hard-code as Long but also supports other types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where this `process` method originates from, as you don't include it in any of your classes that you listed.  However, because this method will simply create and return a new class depending on one of its arguments, it would be better off as a `static` utility method, which wouldn't require it to be overridden.  Also, the `file` parameter isn't even used, so it can be removed:

```
public static ProcessorResult<T> process(T result) {
    return new ProcessorResultImpl<T>(result);
}
```

The method can now be called in the following way to produce the equivalent output from before:

```
public class ... implements ...<Long> {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Somewhere.process(10L);
    }

}
```

Comment: Edited my post(above) with class within process() method is defined, my main goal is to return ProcessResult<T> which T type is going to be either Long or Integer depending whether it's small or big file.

Comment: @user8071107 If that's the case, then there's no need to use `T` if you only plan to return either an `Integer` or `Long`.  Simply use `Number` and return either `Integer` or `Long` at runtime, as they both extend `Number` and won't require explicit type-casting.

Comment: I would probably do that if it wasn't one of requirements. Is there any way to  keep that ProcessorResult<T> and return it somehow already with defined type ?

Comment: You really should have mentioned these constraints earlier so I don't have to keep changing around my answer, but the best you can do is, instead of `T`, define the class as `T extends Number`.  It's still generic, and you should still be able to return either an `Integer` or `Long` at runtime.

Comment: It would mean a lot if you could put some simple example of doing so here, as I tried it and I'm stucked with bunch of errors ;/ .